Boost R-tree - How to sample random element efficiently
I am using a boost library R-tree to store values in a 2D space. I am trying to find a way to effectively sample random values from the R-tree.
So far I have tried 2 methods to do this, both have drawbacks. First of all is by generating a random point within the bounds of the tree then finding the nearest neighbour:
namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;
typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;
typedef bg::model::box<point> box;
typedef std::pair<point, indiv> value;

struct indiv {
    int ID;
    double someVal;
};


value randValueNN() { 

    std::vector<value> randPointVec;

    bg::model::box<point> bounds;
    bounds = tree.bounds();

boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<double> distX(bounds.min_corner().get<0>(), bounds.max_corner().get<0>());
    boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<double> distY(bounds.min_corner().get<1>(), bounds.max_corner().get<1>());

    point randPoint = point(distX(rng), distY(rng));

    tree.query(bgi::nearest(randPoint, 1), std::back_inserter(randPointVec));

    value result = randPointVec[0];

    return result;
};

This can work great and is very fast. However, if there are areas within the space that have a high density of points, the values towards the centre of these dense areas are less likely to be chosen.
Alternatively, I have also tried iterating through the R-tree to find a random nth value:
value randValueIter() {

    int treeSize = tree.size();

    auto it = tree.begin();

    int randIndex = Crand::rand_int(1, treeSize);

    std::advance(it, randIndex);

    return *it;
};

This method is effective but is very slow in comparison. I was wondering if there is an better way of randomly choosing a value in the R-tree that is unbiased and quick?

"However, if there are areas within the space that have a high density of points, the values towards the centre of these dense areas are less likely to be chosen" - in many applications this makes the most sense. You don't need geospatial indexing for a uniform random sampling in the first place.

I reworded your two existing implementations:
value pickA() const {
    value result;
    tree_.query(bgi::nearest(randomPoint(tree_.bounds()), 1), &result);
    return result;
}

value pickB() const {
    return *std::next(tree_.begin(), std::uniform_int_distribution(0ul, tree_.size() - 1)(URBG));
};

Now, if your tree is relatively static (i.e. does not get modified a lot) let's see whether caching the iterators speeds things up:
mutable std::vector<Tree::const_iterator> cache_;

value pickC() const {
    assert(!tree_.empty());
    if (cache_.empty())
        for (auto it = tree_.begin(); it != tree_.end(); ++it)
            cache_.push_back(it);

    Tree::const_iterator pick;
    std::sample(begin(cache_), end(cache_), &pick, 1, URBG);
    return *pick;
}

value pickD() const {
    assert(!tree_.empty() && !cache_.empty());
    Tree::const_iterator pick;
    std::sample(begin(cache_), end(cache_), &pick, 1, URBG);
    return *pick;
}

Generalizing some things into a benchmark:
Live On Coliru
#define NDEBUG
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
#include <random>

namespace bg  = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;
using point   = bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian>;
using box     = bg::model::box<point>;
struct indiv {
    int    ID;
    double someVal;
};
using value = std::pair<point, indiv>;

static std::mt19937 URBG{std::random_device{}()};
// thread_local std::minstd_rand URBG{std::random_device{}()};

static point randomPoint(box const& b) {
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distX(b.min_corner().get<0>(), b.max_corner().get<0>());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distY(b.min_corner().get<1>(), b.max_corner().get<1>());

    return point{distX(URBG), distY(URBG)};
}

template <typename... Args> struct X {
    X(size_t n, box const& b = {{-50, -50}, {50, 50}}) {
        cache_.reserve(n);
        for (int id = 0; size_t(id) < n; ++id)
            tree_.insert(value{randomPoint(b), {id, id * 3.14}});
    }

    value pickA() const {
        value result;
        tree_.query(bgi::nearest(randomPoint(tree_.bounds()), 1), &result);
        return result;
    }

    value pickB() const {
        return *std::next(tree_.begin(), std::uniform_int_distribution(0ul, tree_.size() - 1)(URBG));
    };

    value pickC() const { // use cached iterators
        assert(!tree_.empty());
        ensure_cache();

        return pickD();
    }

    value pickD() const { // don't ensure cache
        assert(!tree_.empty() && !cache_.empty());

        typename Tree::const_iterator pick;
        std::sample(begin(cache_), end(cache_), &pick, 1, URBG);
        return *pick;
    }

  private:
    void ensure_cache() const {
        if (cache_.empty())
            for (auto it = tree_.begin(); it != tree_.end(); ++it)
                cache_.push_back(it);
    }
    void invalidate_cache() const { cache_.clear(); }

    using Tree = bgi::rtree<value, Args...>;
    Tree                                               tree_;
    mutable std::vector<typename Tree::const_iterator> cache_;
};

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

template <typename... Args> void benchmark() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    constexpr auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;

    auto start = now();
    using T = X<Args...>;
    T const x(100'000);
    std::cout << "Construction took " << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms\n";

    for (auto method : {&T::pickA, &T::pickB, &T::pickC, &T::pickD}) {
        auto   start = now();
        double sum   = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10'000; ++i)
            sum += (x.*method)().second.someVal;

        std::cout << std::setw(11) << sum << " in " << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    benchmark<bgi::rstar<16>>();
    benchmark<bgi::rstar<32>>();
    benchmark<bgi::rstar<32, 8>>();
    benchmark<bgi::rstar<32, 16>>();
    benchmark<bgi::linear<32>>();
    benchmark<bgi::quadratic<32>>();
}

Shows e.g.:
void benchmark() [Args = <boost::geometry::index::rstar<16>>]
Construction took 189ms
1.57008e+09 in 17ms
1.55049e+09 in 1742ms
1.56639e+09 in 3474ms
1.56815e+09 in 3488ms
void benchmark() [Args = <boost::geometry::index::rstar<32>>]
Construction took 361ms
1.56092e+09 in 21ms
1.56579e+09 in 1260ms
1.57449e+09 in 3351ms
1.59015e+09 in 3454ms
void benchmark() [Args = <boost::geometry::index::rstar<32, 8>>]
Construction took 379ms
1.56251e+09 in 23ms
1.56598e+09 in 1292ms
1.56405e+09 in 3458ms
1.58474e+09 in 3536ms
void benchmark() [Args = <boost::geometry::index::rstar<32, 16>>]
Construction took 335ms
1.57983e+09 in 22ms
1.56799e+09 in 1260ms
1.57498e+09 in 3539ms
1.56955e+09 in 3400ms
void benchmark() [Args = <boost::geometry::index::linear<32>>]
Construction took 36ms
 1.5855e+09 in 47ms
 1.5715e+09 in 1275ms
1.58203e+09 in 3414ms
1.56222e+09 in 3360ms
void benchmark() [Args = <boost::geometry::index::quadratic<32>>]
Construction took 57ms
1.57482e+09 in 25ms
1.57325e+09 in 1289ms
1.55841e+09 in 3410ms
 1.5738e+09 in 3494ms

Summary/Conclusions?
You might want to tune the actual data distribution, query volumes, packing algorithm etc. to taste.
To me, it confirms that, fortunately rtree::const_iterator was implemented well enough for the cache to be unnecessary. And simple is always better!
Also, note that with uniform tree elements you get uniform sampling either way, as you already know. You also want to benchmark with some denser areas.

Basic implementation, using Boost.Geometry's R-tree.
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;
typedef bg::model::box<point> box;
typedef std::pair<point, indiv> value;

struct indiv {
    int ID;
    double someVal;
};

// Function to randomly select an item from a vector with weighted probabilities
template<typename T>
const T& weighted_random_select(const std::vector<T>& items, const std::vector<double>& weights, std::mt19937& rng) {
    std::discrete_distribution<int> dist(weights.begin(), weights.end());
    return items[dist(rng)];
}

value hierarchical_random_sample(bgi::rtree<value, bgi::quadratic<16>>& tree) {
    std::mt19937 rng(std::random_device{}());
    auto node = tree.root();

    while (!node.is_leaf()) {
        std::vector<bgi::rtree< value, bgi::quadratic<16> >::node_type> children(node.children().begin(), node.children().end());
        std::vector<double> weights;
        for (const auto& child : children) {
            weights.push_back(static_cast<double>(child.second.count));
        }

        node = weighted_random_select(children, weights, rng);
    }

    // Now node is a leaf node, randomly select an element
    const auto& values = node.values();
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, values.size() - 1);
    return values[dist(rng)];
}


Pretty interesting. My rtree implementation doesn't seem to have root() or children() members. Can you show this live on Coliru or Compiler Explorer?
